# Can I disable interactive shell access while tunneling web traffic through SSH?

Tags: security, ssh, proxy, shell, socks

I am looking into implementing SSH tunneling as a cheap VPN solution for outside users to access Intranet-only facing web applications.

I currently am using Ubuntu Server 10.04.1 64 bit with OpenSSH installed.

I am using Putty on Windows boxes to create a tunnel on a local port to my ssh server.

```
start putty -D 9999 mysshserver.com -N
```

I then use tell Firefox to use a SOCKS proxy on localhost:9999.

The -N flag will disable the interactive shell from the client side.  Is there a way to do this on the server side?

Besides disabling root access, using rsa key authentication, and changing the default port; are there any other obvious security practices I should follow for this purpose?  My goal is to simply be able to tunnel web traffic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After four years this answer deserved an update. While originally I used `authorized_keys` myself and would probably use it still in some select cases, you can also use the central `sshd_config` server configuration file.

### sshd_config

You can designate (for your particular use case) a group, such as `proxy-only` or `Match` individual users. In `sshd_config`. This is done after the global settings and revokes, repeats or refines some of the settings given in the global settings.

**Note:** some of the syntax/directives used in [`sshd_config(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) are documented in the `man` page for `ssh_config(5)`. In particular make sure to read the **PATTERNS** section of [`ssh_config(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html).

For a group this means your `Match` block would begin like this:

```
Match group proxy-only
```

You can `Match` the following criteria: `User`, `Group`, `Host`, `LocalAddress`, `LocalPort` and `Address`. To match several criteria simply comma-separate the criteria-pattern pairs (`group proxy-only` above).

Inside such a block, which is traditionally indented accordingly for brevity (but needn't to), you can then declare the settings you want to apply for the user group without having to edit every single `authorized_keys` file for members of that group.

The `no-pty` setting from `authorized_keys` would be mirrored by a `PermitTTY no` setting and `command="/sbin/nologin"` would become `ForceCommand /sbin/nologin`.

Additionally you can also set more settings to satisfy an admin's paranoia, such as `chroot`-ing the user into his home folder and would end up with something like this:

```
Match group proxy-only
    PermitTTY no
    ForceCommand /sbin/nologin
    ChrootDirectory %h
    # Optionally enable these by un-commenting the needed line
    # AllowTcpForwarding no
    # GatewayPorts yes
    # KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
    # PasswordAuthentication no
    # PubkeyAuthentication yes
    # PermitRootLogin no
```

(check yourself whether you need or want the commented out lines and uncomment as needed)

The `%h` is a token that is substituted by the user's home directory (`%u` would yield the user name and `%%` a percent sign). I've found `ChrootDirectory` particularly useful to confine my `sftp-only` users:

```
Match group sftp-only
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

Please mind that only *certain* directives can be used in a `Match` block. Consult the `man` page [`sshd_config(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) for details (search for `Match`).

### authorized_keys

*NB:* the part below this remark was my original answer. Meanwhile - but it also depends on the features of your exact `sshd` version - I would go for the method described above in most cases.

Yes you can, as fine-grained as you can assign public keys. In addition to nologin as recommended by ajdecon, I would suggest setting the following in front of the key entry in `authorized_keys`:

```
no-pty ssh-rsa ...
```

The no pty tells the server-side that no pseudo-terminal should be allocated for that key.

You can also force the execution of something like nologin for a particular key by prepending this:

```
command="/sbin/nologin",no-pty ssh-rsa ...
```

Comment: Please note that `no-pty` alone won't prevent user of the key from executing commands. See https://superuser.com/q/1230979/195460 .

Answer (score 4):

For any tunnelling-only user, change their login shell to /sbin/nologin.  That way your user will be unable to access a shell on the server, but will still be able to run set up ssh tunnels from their client.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are ready to give up user/pass authentication and use keys for logging in, you can specify *parameter*s to each public key.

Notable parameters are:

> **command="command"**
>
> Specifies that the command is executed whenever this key is used for authentication.  The command supplied by the user (if any) is ignored.

and

> **restrict**
>
> Enable all restrictions, i.e. disable port, agent and X11 forwarding, as well as disabling PTY allocation and execution of ~/.ssh/rc.

and finally

> **port-forwarding**
> Enable port forwarding previously disabled by the restrict option.

With these you can pretty much restrict the user of that particular key pair what (s)he can do with the SSH session.

It would look like this:

```
restrict,port-forwarding,command="/sbin/nologin" ssh-rsa <base64-encoded key>
```

Comment: I see my answer is somewhat redundant to https://serverfault.com/a/242411/13364, but I left it in because of the 'restrict' and 'port-forwarding' parameters, which in my opinion better than 'no-pty'.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be the answer you're looking for, but have you considered using OpenVPN as an alternative?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend trying [Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier). It's a heck of a lot easier to configure/manage.